# Overriding non-visible S3 method within namespace

Tags: r

First I have a package called `DataBaseLayer` and it has an S3 method called `LoadFromTable(data_request)`. Second there is another package called `RiskCalculator` which determines several types of risks and does requests to the database by means of the package `DataBaseLayer`. Before "triggering" `RiskCalculator` (by means of an execute function defined in it) a connection to some schema of the database is set up and the method `LoadFromTable` will refer to that particular schema.

For some tests that I need to perform I have to switch schema depending on the value in `data_request` that enters `LoadFromTable(data_request)`. Thus what I actually need is to insert a little check in `LoadFromTable`. As a note, currently there is only a default method implemented, i.e. `LoadFromTable.default`, and it would thus suffice even to only insert that check in that specific method.

My question is thus twofold:
1. Is there a general way to insert a piece of code before any `LoadFromTable` method is called, naively said: to insert a piece of code just before `UseMethod("LoadFromTable", data_request)` is "called".
2. If there is no such way, can we at least insert a piece of code just before `LoadFromTable.default` is called (for in my case that would now suffice).

As a final note, I can imagine you might say that the whole structure should be changed, and I agree, however, that is not an option for I am not the owner of these packages.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is data_request something that you pass to a function in RiskCalculator that it in turn passes  to LoadDataFrame in DataBaseLayer or does RiskCalculator manufacture data_request?

Comment: To be more specific, what happens is: `RiskCalculator` calls a function `GetRisks()`, which is located in a package called `Common` and this function creates `data_request` and calls `LoadFromTable(data_request)` in `DataBaseLayer`. Furthermore, RiskCalculator imports Common, and Common imports DataBaseLayer.

Comment: You may indeed suggest to override `GetRisks()` instead, and that would then fix the issue for a very specific case, because `LoadFromTable` gets called in various manners, not only by means of `GetRisks()`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s strongly discouraged, and fundamentally the wrong approach, to change code in loaded packages, so I won’t discuss it here (but I’ll mention that this is done via the [`assignInNamespace` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/getFromNamespace.html)).

But your case can be solved much easier: just override the `LoadFromTable` generic function in the `RiskCalculator` package as follows:

```
LoadFromTable = function (request) {
    # TODO: perform your check here.
    DataBaseLayer::LoadFromTable(request)
}
```

Now if you load your `RiskCalculator` package and call the function either explicitly (via `RiskCalculator::LoadFromTable`) or implicitly (via `LoadFromTable` after attaching the `RiskCalculator` package), your implementation will be called.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by overriding `LoadFromTable` within `RiskCalculator`? For if I try to unlock the binding `LoadFromTable` within either the namespace or the package environment I get the error `no binding for "LoadFromTable"`... I may not fully understand the idea behind generic function.

Comment: @NMeibergen Just add the above function to your own package/code.

Comment: Given that the hierarchy is such that `RiskCalculator` depends on `DataBaseLayer` (by means of an import statement in its namespace), it will therefore look for first for `LoadFromTable` and will thus first encounter it in DataBaseLayer, before getting to .GlobalEnv, where my code is located. Am I missing something?

Comment: @NMeibergen Ah. I thought `RiskCalculator` was under your control. In that case the only way is via `assignInNamespace`, and to shout at the package maintainers to write extensible code.

Comment: I just posted a question on the assignInNamespace on the same issue as above. You may be of help. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477121/overriding-an-s3-methods-not-fully-successfull. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `trace`:

```
library(DataBaseLayer)
trace(LoadFromTable, quote(print("Hello")))
```

The library statement is important, even if you don't otherwise access that package yourself.